# Teamcity nuget installer not running install.ps1

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I have an ASP.NET application that consumes a nuget package that I also wrote. The nuget package has an install.ps1 script that is invoked when I install the nuget into my solution with VS2015. However, when my Team City build server attempts to compile the project, it fails because there are steps performed in the install.ps1 that it is dependent on. From what I have read, this is because the Team City nuget installer uses the nuget.exe command line and does not support install.ps1 scripts. Looking for a solution.

Thanks,

Joseph

Comment: Seems that it is by design, here is pretty good description: http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2013/12/09/nuget-package-restore-misconceptions.aspx